# save a file with exist file name by mistake in Ubuntu

Tags: save, ubuntu-14.04, gedit

I have a .cpp file named "LocalMap.cpp" in my folder in Ubuntu OS 14.04, then I saved another file named "LocalMap.cpp" with gedit in the same folder by mistake. So the last file content missing, and it's not in the Trash.
Is that possible to find the last file?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: $ cd /your LocalMap.cpp file path
$ ls
$gedit LocalMap.cpp~
This is my old one, i find it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You just overwritten the old file. Entire content of the last file is replaced with new content. So you just lost the old file content. You cannot recover from the trash folder. Files are moved to trash folder only when you delete the file. In this case you just lost the old file content.